# How can I achieve node expansion and collapsing in Neo4j Bloom visualization

Tags: graph, neo4j, graph-visualization, neo4j-browser, neo4j-bloom

**Title:** How can I achieve node expansion and collapsing in Neo4j Bloom visualization?

**Question:**
I'm currently using Neo4j Bloom to visualize a complex graph dataset, and I'm wondering if there's a way to expand and collapse nodes within the visualization. The dataset I'm working with has multiple layers of relationships, and as a result, the visualization can become quite cluttered and hard to navigate.

I've looked through the Neo4j Bloom documentation and interface, but I can't seem to find a direct option for expanding and collapsing nodes like you would in some other visualization tools. Is this functionality supported in Neo4j Bloom, and if so, how can I achieve it?

I'm interested in making the visualization more interactive and user-friendly by allowing users to focus on specific parts of the graph while collapsing less relevant nodes. Any insights, examples, or pointers to relevant resources would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Bloom does not have a collapse feature. Probably the closest to collapse would be to select nodes you want to keep and click "dismiss other nodes". There's a bit more info on that in the docs: https://neo4j.com/docs/bloom-user-guide/current/bloom-visual-tour/bloom-scene-interactions/